# How to aid Smaz in further compressing repeating characters?

Tags: string, compression

Smaz is able to compress a short string (< 100 bytes) where other compressing tools fail.

But there is a problem with it, particularly repeating characters that it doesn't optimize by itself.

For example the string "this is a short string" compresses fine:

```
\x9b8\xac>\xbb\xf2>\xc3F
```

It is 9 bytes long. But if you have a short string with repeating characters you have a problem.. for example the string "this is a string with many aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa's" compresses into this:

```
\x9b8\xac>\xc3F\xf3\xe3\xad\tG\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\xfe'\n
```

It is still smaller, but the many "\x04"'s look like a waste of space.

I've been thinking about calculating a letter occurrence and replacing it with a sort of "bookmark".. for example "aaaaaaaaaa" with ten "a" occurrences becomes "a//10".

This is a test Python snippet I've created out of my head, but is very very ugly as of now

```
a = set("this is a string with many aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa's")
b = "this is a string with many aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa's"

for i in a:
    if i+i in b: # if char occ. > 2
        o = b.count(i) - 2 
        s = i*o
        c = b.replace(s, i+'//'+str(o))

print c
```

It then becomes:

```
this is a string with many a//22's
```

Smaz compressed

```
\x9b8\xac>\xc3F\xf3\xe3\xad\tG\x04\xc5\xc5\xff\x0222'\n
```

My worry is, what if the string contains an url? Is it safe to escape it like "//"? but then you have regex strings. How can it be escaped in that case?

Finally, my clear and concise question is: How do you safely shorten repeating characters that Smaz doesn't compress by itself?

Answer (score -1):

How do you safely shorten repeating characters that Smaz doesn't compress by itself?

You can't without changing the Smaz algorithm and being incompatible with Smaz.

Smaz is purpose built to be effective on small strings because its dictionary is universal and pre-computed. Other compression schemes need to build up a dictionary that is data set dependent, and typically takes a few hundred bytes for you to see positive returns. Repeating sequences are rare in short strings.

For your proposed Smaz variant with run length encoding scheme to work you would have to take up one of the 256 precious byte slots Smaz reserves for its codes. You could change one of the byte slots to mean "a byte indicating length to follow, followed by the byte to be repeated" - i.e., 3 bytes to communicate [REPEAT BYTE] [BYTE indicating 2 - 257 times] [BYTE CODE TO REPEAT]. You could reassign the Smaz byte code 253 from its present meaning of ".com" for the purpose of run-length encoding. But be aware that your compression will be slightly less effective for general data with ".com".

Also be aware that searching for repeating sequences in a hypothetical Smaz variant with run-length encoding would necessarily take more CPU compute time for the backtracking compression.

Comment: Using PeterSO's code, try compressing and decompressing `"\tA\r\nB\r\nC"` and tell us what happens.

Comment: That string has nothing to do with what Smaz output looks like.

Comment: You're missing the point completely. Try compressing it with Smaz and then PeterSO's code and you'll find it will not work. All ASCII characters below 32 (space) will conflict with his run length scheme.

Comment: A simpler example: The string "the tin" Smazzes to "\x01\x0e\x0f". Try that with the code in question.